# ¿Cómo mostrar datos en un DataTable hasta que termine de cargar la pagina?

Tags: html, datatables

Estoy implementando DataTable para mostrar aproximadamente 9 mil registros.
Al leer la documentación de DataTable e implementarlo, realizo una prueba y me carga correctamente los archivos pero el problema es que al entrar a la pagina o al recargar, primero me carga los archivos y después el datatable, es decir... Primero me muestra los registros sin estilos como una tabla norma, después de que termine de cargar la pagina ya me muestra la tabla formada correctamente.

Ejemplo al recargar la pagina:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo después que termine de carga:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay alguna manera en la cual pueda optimizar o cargar primero el DataTable y después los registros?

Este es mi código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="iso-8859-1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="imgs/icon/favicon.ico"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <title>Autodiagn&oacute;stico</title>
</head>
<body>

<table id="table_id" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
  

<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>  
<script src="js/utiles.js"></script>
<script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
              var table =  $('#table_id').DataTable( {
                "fnInitComplete": function (oSettings, json) {
        },
                      "order": [[ 0, 'desc' ]],
                      "language": {
                        "decimal":        "",
                        "emptyTable":     "No hay datos disponibles",
                        "info":           "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
                        "infoEmpty":      "Mostrando 0 a 0 de 0 registros",
                        "infoFiltered":   "(filtrado de _MAX_ registros totales)",
                        "infoPostFix":    "",
                        "thousands":      ",",
                        "lengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                        "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                        "processing":     "Procesando...",
                        "search":         "Buscar:",
                        "zeroRecords":    "No se encontraron coincidencias",
                        "paginate": {
                            "first":      "Primero",
                            "last":       "Último",
                            "next":       "Siguiente",
                            "previous":   "Anterior"
                        },
                        "aria": {
                            "sortAscending":  ": activate to sort column ascending",
                            "sortDescending": ": activate to sort column descending"
                        }
                      },
                      "scrollX": true, 
                      "columnDefs": [
                        { "width": "50", "targets": 0 }
                      ]
                  } );
          } );
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Soy de la opinión y por eso comento, no veo usable renderizar 9000 registros para que se conviertan en un datatables del lado del cliente. En lo personal me voy por la vía de datatables con procesamiento del lado del servidor, tu datatables se construiría solo con los registros de la página actual en cuestión. Se te pueden dar muchos ejemplos de esta funcionalidad de datatables.

Answer (score 0):

Yo separo los elementos del dataTable, la parte del HTML hago su declaración

```html
<div class="panel-body">
        <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">
            <table id="nombreDeMiTabla"  class="table table-striped table-bordered  table-responsive dataTable_width_auto display" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="font-size:10px; background-color: #5CB85C;">DATO 1</th>
                    <th style="font-size:10px; background-color: #5CB85C;">DATO 2</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                 <tbody>
                 <tr>
                 <?PHP
                for($i=0; $i< $totalResultadoConsulta; $i++){
                  $PrimerDato=$resultadoConsulta[$i]->getPrimerDato();
$SegundoDato=$resultadoConsulta[$i]->getSegundoDato();
 ?>
 <tr>
     <td label style="font-size:10px;"><?= $PrimerDato></td>
     <td label style="font-size:10px;"><?= $SegundoDato></td>
 </tr>

                 <?PHP
                    }
                    ?>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                 <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th style="font-size:10px; background-color: #5CB85C;">DATO 1</th>
                    <th style="font-size:10px; background-color: #5CB85C;">DATO 2</th>
                      
                </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
```

En un archivo JS hago la llamada al dataTable de esta manera:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#nombreDeMiTabla').DataTable({
        "language": {
            "url": "librerias_auxiliares/Bootstrap/js/español.json",
        }   
        });
```

});

Y aunque revisando la ruta esta un poco rara, pero bueno dentro de carpeta  llamada librerias_auxiliares y de Bootstrap (No recuerdo por que lo puse ahí) en un js cargo los datos de conversión del idioma al español.

Esto te lo comento por que veo que en tu tabla al menos la que pones de ejemplo están en ingles todos los elementos.

Te recomiendo revisar las aperturas y cierres de etiquetas en ocasiones eso hace que los dataTables se comporten de manera extraña.

Saludos

Comment: Una duda,  no entiendo bien a que hace referencia sobre separar los elementos del DataTabla, tengo el mismo ejemplo en ASP, pero me da el mismo resultado

Comment: Buenas Tardes Julio no soy muy bueno para explicar,  yo me base un poco mas en este "modelo"  https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4 , lo único que se me ocurre es que cambies el orden de tu código. Que pongas primero la declaración de dataTable antes de los datos.  <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
              var table =  $('#table_id').DataTable( { } </script>